# ES-linting multiple Javascript files used together yields complaints about undefined globals

Tags: javascript, global-variables, eslint

I have an HTML page (well, more like XUL or XHTML, but never mind) which uses several `<script>` tags, including several `.js` files. Some of these define globals, and the other `.js` files use these globals.

When I run [eslint](https://eslint.org/) on these files, I get errors about these globals, in the files where they are used without being defined, e.g.:

```
  4:1  error  'MyGlobal' is not defined  no-undef
```

No, of course I could disable the "no-undef" rule of eslint, but I *do* want to find use of undefined values. Is there a way I can inform it about the relation between my files?

Comment: https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/language-options#specifying-globals?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Can you be more specific?